# Criar um scrollable tabs com javascript

Tags: javascript, css

O que é que vocês recomendam para criar uma scrollable tabs com Javascript?

Comment: O que é para você um scrolable menu? pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Eu quis dizer scrollable tabs, como a ideia é implementar um menu então fiquei com aquilo preso na cabeça...

Comment: Hmmm ainda não está claro... tipo isto: __http://jsfiddle.net/veJf9/5/__ ?

Comment: Do estilo do menu do google paly ---> http://i.stack.imgur.com/c0uIB.jpg

Comment: Dei uma sugestão na forma de resposta. A tua pergunta não esclarece bem o pretendido nem o objectivo do que estás a tentar criar. Se não ajudar, recomendo que elabores a pergunta dando conta do que estás a tentar fazer, para que dispositivo e que ferramentas ou bibliotecas estás já a utilizar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se jQuery for uma solução, existe um PlugIn para a jQuery-UI que te permite adicionar essa funcionalidade aos Separadores.

## [jQuery-ui Scrollable tabs plugin v1.0](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-scrollable-tabs/)

#### Funciona em:

- Firefox 3.6+
- Internet Explorer 7+
- Opera 10.10+
- Chrome 5.0+
- Safari 4.0+

## Instruções para implementação

- Inclusão das bibliotecas necessárias

  Em primeiro Será necessário incluir a biblioteca jQuery que vai tornar a utilização deste PlugIn possível.

  Após isso, é necessário incluir a biblioteca da jQueryUI.

  Em último lugar o PlugIn que vai permitir atingir o que pretendes, o jQuery-ui Scrollable Tabs.

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollabletab.js"></script>
  ```
- Inclusão do CSS necessário

  O único CSS necessário é o que vem com a jQuery UI que pode ser [qualquer um dos temas](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) que pretendas.

  ```
  <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  ```
- Inicializar o PlugIn

  Ao inicializar o PlugIn é necessário em primeiro inicializar o PlugIn das *tags* da jQuery UI e só depois o PlugIn para as tornar *scrollable*.

  ```
  var $tabs = $('#tabs')
                  .tabs()             //jQuery ui tabs
                  .scrollabletab()    //jQuery scrollable tabs
  ```

## Resultado

O resultado como podes ver na página de exemplos são separadores com adição de setas de navegação para fazer *scroll* direita/esquerda nas mesmas.

[image: Captura de tela]